# using of soundpool for playing sound causes cutoff of sound

Tags: android

I am using soundpool to play sound but i observe that sound gets cut off. Only half of sound plays. I dont know what is happening.
I am using sound when i stretch the arrow and when it touches any object it plays.I am sharing code

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sampleId, int status) {
        soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    }
});
soundPool.load(GameActivity.this, R.raw.btn_click, 1);`
```

Anyone aware about this.

Answer (score 0):

SoundPool is used to play small length of sounds. It have maximum buffer limit of 1MB. It decompresses audio file to pcm format, which depends on sampling rate and length of song. So your file may not need to be actually of 1MB.

For lengthy sounds you can use android's [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: But my sound file size is only 12kb

Comment: @Shivanikedar what is the length and sampling rate of audio file. File formats like mp3 or ogg are compressed, so on decompressing to pcm increases file size.
You may try to decode it to pcm online and check the results.

Comment: It is ogg farmat

Comment: Have you tried decompressing, if not pcm you can get closer to approximate decompressed size when converting to wav.

Comment: How to decompress it.

Comment: Try any online converter (like [this](http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav)). Anyways if you are still stuck, you can give MediaPlayer a try.

Comment: I tried media player as my first preference but there was same problem. I dont know why this is happening.